# Problema com rotas no axios + laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

Eu estou usando `vue.js` com `axios` para fazer *cruds* mas estou com uma duvida  sobre rotas.

Tenho as seguintes rotas:

```
| DELETE   | admin/deleteprod/{id}    | componet_3.produtos | App\Http\Controllers\ProdutoController@destroy                                   
| PUT      | admin/updateprod/{id}    | componet_2.produtos | App\Http\Controllers\ProdutoController@update
```

**Estou usando os seguintes métodos:**

```
  updat:function(id){
      var url='updateprod/'+ id;  
     axios.put(url,  this.fillproduto).then(response=>{

        this.getProdutos();
        this.fillproduto={'id':'','nome_pro':'','descricao_pro':'' };
        $('#edit').modal('toggle');

    });
    console.log(url);

    }, 

   deleteprod:function(id){
    var url='deleteprod/'+ id;
    axios.delete(url).then(response=>{
        this.getProdutos(); 
    });
    //alert('id'); 
    console.log(url); 
  } ,
```

Como podem ver, eu não estou usando a **url** inteira nos métodos só o ultimo parâmetro, isso porquê se eu usar a *url* inteira, o método para de funcionar.

A minha duvida é se isso é normal e se pode gerar algum problema futuro na minha aplicação. Não achei nenhuma documentação a respeito.

Comment: Sim. Você poderá ter problemas. Se você tiver na página incial (`/`), a requisição será feita para `https://www.example.com/updateprod/<id>`, porém se você tiver em uma *sub-página* (`/category/t-shirt`), a requisição será feita para `https://www.example.com/category/t-shirt/updateprod/<id>`. P.S.: A não ser que você configure a opção `baseURL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duas dicas:

1. Recomendo você definir o `baseUrl` no axios e caso precise acessar outra url, basta utilizar o caminho absoluto `/o-path` ou uma nova url `http://..../o-path`.

Você pode utilizar o Axios.create() para isso.

2. Não precisa adicionar no path "update" ou "delete" ... O verbo (PUT/DELETE/...) já serve para isso.

Seu endpoint ficaria `PUT admin/{id}`. O verbo PUT, você já sabe que é um update.

Configurações do Axios:
- https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config

Comment: Muito obrigada pela dica Eduardo Stuart!!!